# Online tools for checking validity of classical, intuitionistic, ... logic formulas?

Tags: propositional-calculus, predicate-logic, first-order-logic, online-resources, constructive-mathematics

What online tools are available, where one can enter a formula of (first order) propositional or predicate logic, and have it check whether it is valid classically, intuitionistically, or even minimally or in some other logical framework?

I found the following things that got close:

- In the past I have successfully used LWB (The Logics Workbench) at http://www.lwb.unibe.ch/shell/.  However, it currently (Feb 2, 2015) fails with HTTP error 500 problems, where the server cannot connect to *something* on localhost port 11111.
- The Stanford Validity Checker (http://verify.stanford.edu/SVC/) has been available at least up until May 2014 ([archive.org link](http://web.archive.org/web/20140526073024/http://verify.stanford.edu/SVC/)) but it now (Feb 2, 2015) gives an HTTP 403 Forbidden error.
- Only classical logic is supported by [somerby.net/mack/logic](http://somerby.net/mack/logic/).
- Also only classical logic is supported by the [ProB Logic Calculator](http://www.stups.uni-duesseldorf.de/ProB/index.php5/ProB_Logic_Calculator).

The last two I found through Leslie Lamport's [Logic Calculators](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/um/people/lamport/tla/logic-calculators.html) page, which ominously proclaims: "Logic calculators are disappearing faster than I learn about them."

As background, among other things I'd like to use such a tool to help answer questions on this site like [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1130817/11994) and [this](https://math.stackexchange.com/q/1128646/11994).

**Update.** Pointers to easily available and free Linux or Windows based tools are also welcome, but the main goal of this question is for online tools.

Comment: As a side note: you can donwload the LWB

Answer (score 4):

[A Linear Logic Prover](http://bach.istc.kobe-u.ac.jp/llprover/) supports propositional and unary predicate logic in three different frameworks; one is classical and the other two are intuitionistic.  It seems to work ok.  If you enter the statement from "[Intuitionistic proof of ∀x(P(x)∨Q(x))→(∀xP(x)∨∃xQ(x))](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1130817/intuitionistic-proof-of-forall-xpx-lor-qx-to-forall-x-px-lor-exists-x)", which is "`all(X,p(X)+q(X)) -> (all(X,p(X)) + exists(X,q(X)))`" in llprover's language, it finds a proof for it in the classical framework, and fails to find a proof for it in the intuitionistic framework.

Comment: I hope I have not broke anything. I tried to copy paste your sequence and pressed "Enter" instead of pressing "Prove",  now no proofs are avaialable for solving (neither examples) :/

Answer (score 0):

Here is one Windows application that checks and generates proofs for the validity of sentences of propositional truth-functional and modal logic (S5). The program includes also truth tables. The application can be downloaded from:

http://automated-reasoning-tools.scienceontheweb.net/