# Inexpressibility of $\vee$ in term of $\wedge, \to$ and $\bot$ in intuitionistic logic.

Tags: logic, proof-writing

Show that it is not possible to express $\vee$ using $\wedge, \to, \bot$.

I have no idea how to show it. My system is intuitionistic logic.

Comment: Just to be clear $\to$ is implication and $\bot$ is false / contradiction?

Comment: In the title, you refer to "conjunctions" being inexpressible, but in your post, it seems you are suggesting that "disjunction" is inexpressible (using $\land, \rightarrow, \bot$)

Comment: I edited my first title

Comment: The vote to close doesn't make sense: it is quite clear what you are asking, but I have taken the liberty of making the title a bit clearer. It would help if you gave us some context: e.g., where did you come across the question? Do you know about Heyting algebras?

Comment: No, I don't know Heyting algebras

Comment: OK. You will find a proof here http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/1128646/is-lor-definable-in-intuitionistic-logic. Until you learn about Heyting algebras, you will have to take part of the proof on trust. I'm afraid this makes your question a duplicate.

Comment: I suspect he is trying to find a formula $F(a, b)$, such that replacing $\lor \text{Intro}$ and $\lor \text{Elim}$ with the inference $a \lor b := F(a, b)$ results in the same logic.  Or more specifically, he is establishing that such an $F$ as a composition as he described does not exist.